# PHP loading array of objects

Tags: object

I'd like to load my array with objects from .csv

When I do it with writing JSON like a forced string, its okay and my code works fine.

When I try to make objects and load them into an array, new object overwrites all objects in the array and I got an array full of the same values. Any suggestions for my mistakes?

In the end, variable content gives valid JSON (without '[]' brackets), but array contentArr gives array full of same objects...

Here´s the code:

```
            $content = '';
            $contentArr = array();
            $Obj = new stdClass();
            $count = 0;
            while ($csv = fgetcsv($file,1000,",")) {
                    $content .= "{\"number\":\"".$csv[0]=Filter($csv[0])."\",\"message\":\"".$csv[1]."\"},";
                    $count++;
                    $Obj -> number = $csv[0]=Filter($csv[0]);
                    $Obj -> message = $csv[1];
                    $contentArr[] = $Obj;
            }
            $content = substr($content, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED MYSELF.

My mistake was that I was changing link only to one object I made before the while cycle. When I move object creating INTO the while cycle, I am creating new object for every new data I am loading into array.

Code:

```
        $content = '';
        $contentArr = array();
        //$Obj = new stdClass(); ----> this was my mistake
        $count = 0;
        while ($csv = fgetcsv($file,1000,",")) {
                $content .= "{\"number\":\"".$csv[0]=Filter($csv[0])."\",\"message\":\"".$csv[1]."\"},";
                $count++;
                $Obj = new stdClass();// ----> that's how it should be
                $Obj -> number = $csv[0]=Filter($csv[0]);
                $Obj -> message = $csv[1];
                $contentArr[] = $Obj;
        }
        $content = substr($content, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help you

```
 $openFile = fopen($file, "r");
 while(!feof($openFile)){
    $csv = fgetcsv($file);
    //your code here
 }
 fclose($openFile);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a problem, i got a problem with loading objects into array. Getting info from csv is fine. It's only part of my code because original code is long about 400 lines.